# Maven profiles for two separated Jar files

Tags: maven

I have got two Main Classes in a project and I wanted to generate two separated jar files. I found a solution using profiles, but the result I got was wrong. As I use `maven-jar-plugin` and `maven-resource-plugin` for the purpose of excluding properties files from the final jar file, I put both of them inside two separate `<profile>`-s. The only differences are the `<id>` for the different `<profile>` and the main class entries.

Can somebody tell me the correct configuration for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the jar plugin to create artifacts with classifiers. Define the project as `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. Define a profile which is active by default and does the compilation. Make sure you specify phases. Then add two profiles that deal with your packagings. Then also use the build-helper-maven-plugin to attach the artifacts to the project, if necessary.